# Trying to get custom android camera working

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have developed a basic camera and am trying to get it working.

Here is the camera code

```
package com.example.camera;

   import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder holder;
 private Camera camera; 
 Object size;

 public CameraView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        holder = this.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
        holder.addCallback(this);
}
 public Camera getCamera(){
        return camera;
} 

 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

      Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();//Getting paramaters.

        if(size!=null){ //make sure we don't pull a NullException.
                params.setPreviewSize(width, height);//gotta set the size, since we know it. 
        } 
        camera.setParameters(params);//gotta set the paramaters now. 
        camera.startPreview();//starting the preview.
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    try{
        camera = Camera.open();//setting the camera up.
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);//making the display our current SurfaceHolder
} catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();//printing out the error message if it happens.
} 

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;


} 

        }
```

Now Im trying to call the camera from my main method and I just cant seem to make it work

package com.example.camera;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.hardware.Camera;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;

public class main {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     cam = cv.getCamera(); //notice how we used that method? ;)
                     cam.takePicture(null,null,PictureCallback_);

                }
            });
        }
     Camera.PictureCallback PictureCallback_ = new Camera.PictureCallback() {


            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);


                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
            } 
    } ;
```

Any help is appreciated. Trying to call the original camera activity getCamera and then get the picture taken and put it into imageView1 any help is appreciated.

Comment: what errors do you get? give specifics so we can help

Comment: ` I just cant seem to make it work`. Post error/logcat.

Comment: Sorry Im drawing a blank towards the bottom.                      cam = cv.getCamera();
                   cam.takePicture(null,null,PictureCallback_);                                                                                             I cant figure out how to call the getCamera method from the camerview class to allow a picture to be taken

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this in your onClick() method:

```
cam.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback(){
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
          // If you want to play your own sound (otherwise, it plays the sound by default)
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
        cam.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, PictureCallback_);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [camera library project here](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project) you can use this [library](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project/tree/master/Girish%20Camera%20Library%20Project/Library) to call the camera and take pictures and save it  or read code on how to use the camera. [Sample](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project/tree/master/Girish%20Camera%20Library%20Project/CameraSample) is given you can check it out